# Modificar StyleSheet desde consola JS

Tags: javascript, css, datatables, google-developers-console

Buenas noches a todos,

Mi pregunta viene porque no encuentro forma de modificar el archivo de estilos desde la consola de JavaScript, lo que quiero es hacer visible el input Filtro del dataTable, he intentado por ejemplo con `$(".dataTables_filter").display = "true";` pero no parece funcionar, el elemento está allí pero no es visible, alguna ayuda? Gracias!

[image: Tabla]

[image: Hoja de estilo dónde se ve el estilo del elemento oculto]

[image: El elemento está en el código aunque no se muestre en la pagina]

[image: Si modifico la hoja de estilo de forma manual el elemento aparece en la pagina, quiero automatizar esto]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de `true` prueba con `block` o `inline-block`. Además el selector es: `$(".dataTables_filter label")`

También puedes probar el selector completo: `$("div.task_listing .dataTables_filter label").css("display", "block");`

Comment: Gracias! Estás en lo correcto lo que estaba seleccionando solo la clase y me pasaba por alto el label.

Solo por comentar, estoy dando vueltas con esto del dataTables desde hace una semana! No puedo creer que lo que quería hacer se reduzca a una simple linea de código!

Comment: Jejeje Suele suceder. Éxitos!